# Making a query with data from an array in PHP on multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to make a query with data from an array in PHP on multiple columns in a database?

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE Facility1,Facility2,Facility3,Facility4,Facility5,Facility6,Facility7,Facility8,Facility9 = ' { Array Values Here } '
```

I have list of checkbox values stored in an array and I only want to select these. If it is not possible, how else can I run a query to select these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it is possible to query multiple fields:

```
WHERE Facility1 = 'value1' AND Facility2 = 'value2' ...
```

That's standard SQL, you find it documented in the mysql manual as well:

- [MySQL `Select` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)
- [MySQL Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/expressions.html)

For your specific problem (checkbox array values) it heavily depends. You need to map the checkbox array values to the fields in the mysql database to create an SQL statement that makes sense.

As you have not given any information next to that it's an array, there is not much to give as an example but that you map these array values to database columns.

```
$columns = array('Facility1' => 'checkboxname1', 'Facility2' => 'checkboxname2');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE ';
$queryWhereAnd = array();
foreach($columns as $column => $name)
{
    $queryWhereAnd[] = sprintf('%s = \'%s\'', $column, mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$name]));
}
$query .= implode(' AND ', $queryWhereAnd ) . ';';
```

Comment: Are you using the arrays to query the multiple fields?

Comment: @hakre Would there be a way if he HAD to use an array or he would have to iterate through the values using something like a foreach?

Comment: I added some example code chunk, but it's hard to say for the question if it's exactly fitting. So it's just a bare example how some mapping could look like. It does not deal with checkboxes not set (and it assumes POST method), so take care and extend the `foreach` part as needed.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE Facility1 OR Facility2 OR Facility3 OR Facility4 IN ('".implode("','",$option).'\')` - this is what I'm doing right now but the query does not check all the columns. So if something is found in Facility2 for one entry and Facility4 for another then it does not return Facility2 as a result but will return Facility4.

Comment: @methuselah: You syntax is wrong. It's more like `WHERE Facility1 IN (...) OR Facility2 IN (...) OR ...` and so on. Otherwise it just would be a boolean sort of `OR`, like `WHERE TRUE OR TRUE OR FALSE ...` - You first need to learn some of the basics, than it will turn out working for you.

Comment: @hakre Thanks - I'm trying this `$myQuery = "SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE Facility1 IN ('".implode("','",$option).'\') OR Facility2 IN ('".implode("','",$option).'\')";` but keep getting a syntax error. What have I typed in wrong?

Comment: I guess you mixed `"` and `'` somewhere. They need to pair up with each other if you want to successfully define (write) a string value. Additionally, assign `implode("','",$option)` to a variable, so you can re-use it: `$inList = "'".implode("','",$option)."'"; $myQuery = "... IN ($inList) OR Facility2 IN ($inlist)"` and/or similar (just remove duplicate code, less duplication, less errors, better code).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @hakre. I have one more question however. There are two additional fields on my form called Location and RoomType. The SQL now looks like this: `SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE Facility1 IN ($inList) OR Facility2 IN ($inList) OR Facility3 IN ($inList) OR Facility4 IN ($inList) OR Facility5 IN ($inList) OR Facility6 IN ($inList) OR Facility7 IN ($inList) OR Facility8 IN ($inList) OR Facility9 IN ($inList) AND Location LIKE '".$Location."%' AND RoomType LIKE '".$RoomType."%' ORDER BY CONVERT(Capacity, SIGNED)` but it doesn't seem to consider Location and RoomType!

Comment: Like in math, use paranthesis to group conditions: `(A1 OR A2 OR A3) AND B AND C` - This works in SQL, too.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully follow - can you show me an example with a segment of my code?

Comment: No, but with something more similar `1 + 2 * 3 = 7` but (1 + 2) * 3 = 9` - Use brackets to specify the order how the `OR` & `AND` should work together. You first want the checkbox expression, but then you want to have the filter on location and roomtype as well. So you have three decisions that must be matched: A AND B AND C. But A is more complex, so it's `(F1 IN ($) OR F2 IN ($) OR F3 IN ($) ...) AND B AND C`. More visible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here's the format:

```
SELECT *
FROM rooms
WHERE (field1, field2, field3, field4)
 IN
  (('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'))
```

But it's likely to scan all rows (not utilize indexes). It's best split out the values as hakre suggests:

```
WHERE Facility1 = 'value1' AND Facility2 = 'value2' ...
```

Comment: I currently have: `"SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE (Facility1, Facility2, Facility3, Facility4) IN(('".implode("','",$option).'\'))';` - does it mean it will check for matching values in Facility1 OR Facility2 OR Facility3?

Comment: In my example, field1 must match value1, field2 must match value2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The colsest thing to what you're looking for, I think is awful :)

Give this a try:

```
select * from rooms
where (facility1, facility2, facility3) in (select 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3')
```

Make sure the resulting String from PHP results in a similar query.

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2b80/1)

PS: I insist on using ANDs